# Python split list into chunks with repetitions

Tags: python, list

I know that it is possible to do it like this:

```
test_list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

x = 3

final_list= lambda test_list, x: [test_list[i:i+x] for i in range(0, len(test_list), x)]

output=final_list(test_list, x)
output is: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['10']]
```

but I have a bit different requirements. I should return this:

```
output is: [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['8','9', '10']]
```

In other words, I should allow repeating of numbers in the final chunk. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lambda test_list, x: [test_list[min(i,len(test_list)-x):min(i+x,len(test_list))] for i in range(0, len(test_list), x)]
```

Would probably be more efficient to precalculate len(test_list) though

Pretty much:
You said that you wanted the last element to not be the remaining elements, but the last x elements (right?), so that means that if there are less than x elements remaining (ie our index i is greater than or equal to length-x), we do not want to use i as starting index, we want to use length-x.

The second min I used (for the ending index) is not strictly necessary btw, just for cleanliness.

Comment: Make sure you also explain "what did you do" and "why that works" in your answer.

Comment: Why is it "more efficient to precalculate len(test_list)" i.e. since `len(test_list)` is a O(1) operation?

Comment: @DarrylG as a matter of fact,`len` is not a O(1) operation in python; not sure why, but if you don't believe me, run this: `mylist = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"] #* 100000
import time
t1 = time.time()
x = len(mylist)
print(time.time() - t1)
`

Comment: @CesarvanderPoel--with your code I'm getting a time of 0.0.  `timeit` provides a more accurate estimate of time i.e. in Jupyter note book: `%timeit len(mylist)` reports **82.7 ns** with `mylist = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"]` and **99.8 ns** for `mylist = ["apple", "orange", "cherry"] * 100000`/